# How to use log in Mako?

Tags: python, mako

How do I take the 'log' of a particular variable "testvar" in a Mako template? Assume that testvar is already a number. It does not appear clear in the documentation as to how one would do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import `math` inside the template, then call `math.log`:

```
>>> from mako.template import Template
>>> print Template("<%import math%>${math.log(testvar)}").render(testvar=2)
0.69314718056
```